# Sending data in angular $http post

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs

I seem to be having some difficulty sending a val of a selected of a selected item into a new %http post in angular.

I am doing the following:

```
$scope.scope1Change = function() {
          //Build URL based on selection
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/listAreasByScope', 
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            data: { id: $scope.scope1.id }
        })
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.array2 = data.scopes;
        });
    };
```

Where $scope.scope1.id  is the val (which is the id im trying to send) of the previous drop down in which this event is triggered. $scope.scope1.id seems to be storing just fine when I console.log it however when I look at the formdata in the dev console it is formatting very oddly like so -

```
 {"id":2}:
```

It looks like it is recognizing the whole first item as the key. Any way around this? I have tried various ideas with no success.

Thanks!

Comment: A unit test would solve this for you. You could test to see if the right value was being passed as data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use params instead of data. [AngularJs docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

```
$scope.scope1Change = function() {
      //Build URL based on selection
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/listAreasByScope', 
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        params: { id: $scope.scope1.id }
    })
    .success(function(data){
        $scope.array2 = data.scopes;
    });
};
```

Comment: If the value is needing to be tacked onto the querystring this is the right way to do it. Otherwise, the data method is the correct way. However, the question doesn't explicitly state that one way or the other is needed.