# How do I pass model data to a post request?

Tags: angularjs

How do I get the value of an ng-model and place it into a controller post request?

```
    (function(angular) {
    angular.module('urlShortener', ['ngAnimate'])
        .controller('shortenerController', function($scope, $http){
            $scope.customMode = false;
            $scope.passData = function passData(){
                $http.post('/add', {url: raw_url})
                    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        // this callback will be called asynchronously
                        // when the response is available
                    })
                    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                        // or server returns response with an error status.
                    });
            }
        })


})(window.angular);
```

The model i'm using:

```
<input ng-model="raw_url" type="text" placeholder="Paste your url here and we will shrink it!" class="form-control"/>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25411682/sending-data-in-angular-http-post   params.

Comment: ooh.  Deprecation notice for success and error  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, Thanks @SMeaden

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read it from the scope: `$scope.raw_url`

From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel):

> The ngModel directive binds an input,select, textarea (or custom form control) to a property on the scope using NgModelController, which is created and exposed by this directive.

Answer (score 3):

You are nearly there, for every **ng-model** there has to be a binding in the controller which seems to be missing in your case. You can do it in the following way:

```
(function(angular) {
    angular.module('urlShortener', ['ngAnimate'])
        .controller('shortenerController', function($scope, $http){
            $scope.raw_url; //the binding
            $scope.customMode = false;
            $scope.passData = function passData(){
                $http.post('/add', {url: $scope.raw_url}) //raw_url to $scope.raw_url
                    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        // this callback will be called asynchronously
                        // when the response is available
                    })
                    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                        // or server returns response with an error status.
                    });
            }
        })


})(window.angular);
```

However, I would suggest wrapping your post requests in a **service**/**factory** which is the angular way of doing things.

Comment: Never used $resource. What is your suggestion?

Comment: $resource is a layer of abstract that sits above $http and assumes a RESTful/CRUD pattern.

Comment: Ok, will check it out. Up till now I have been using $http with a promise.

Answer (score 1):

`$http.post('/add', {url: raw_url})` in this line replace `raw_url` with `$scope.raw_url`