# How to post the JSON to the given input location using angularjs?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, json, ajax, angular-ngmodel

I have  the following `json`:

```json
var jsondata = {
"id": 1,
"name": "Test Name",
"price": 100,
"city": "XYZ"
};
```

I would like to `post`/`send` this `json` data to some `url location`(I have different `URL locations`, i.e. whatever the `url` `location` I enter in the `input` field, then to that `url location` I need to `post/send` this `json` data) on clicking of `Send` button. I have tried the following, but I am unable to send to the given entered url.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('TestCtrl',function($scope, $http) {
$scope.sendToLocation = function(){
var jsondata = {
"id": 1,
"name": "Test Name",
"price": 100,
"city": "XYZ"
};

 $.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
 dataType: 'json',
 url: 'My URL HERE',
 data: JSON.stringify(jsondata),
 success: function(data) {
 alert("yes, you have posted the data !");
 }
 });
 //alert(JSON.stringify(jsondata));//gives the above json
 };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">  
<br>
<input type="url" maxlength="50" size="50" ng-model="sendToLocation.url"><br><br>
 <button id="sendbutton" type="button" ng-click="sendToLocation()" >Send</button>  
</div>
```

Created [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tu2829ef/2/).

Please let me know what I am doing wrong and how to send the json. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the angular $http service: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

You have already injected it into the controller i.e. "function ($scope, $http)"

Here's the code relating to your fiddle.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.sendToLocation = function() {
    var jsondata = {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Test Name",
      "price": 100,
      "city": "XYZ"
    };

    $http.post($scope.sendToLocation.url, jsondata, {}).then(
      function(response) {
        alert("yes, you have posted the data !");
      },
      function(error) {

      });
    //alert(JSON.stringify(jsondata));//gives the above json
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  <br>
  <input type="url" maxlength="50" size="50" ng-model="sendToLocation.url">
  <br>
  <br>
  <button id="sendbutton" type="button" ng-click="sendToLocation()">Send</button>
</div>
```

And here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ltfleming/tu2829ef/10/

Comment: thanks for your reply, yes, it's working fine ! Thanks for your help !

Comment: I have got one more solution too with: $scope.raw_url; from the post just now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31962868/how-do-i-pass-model-data-to-a-post-request

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.module('myApp', []);
```

you can use $http provider to make http calls,and it is possible to pass data as shown in example.

```
angular
.module('app')
.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.sendToLocation = function () {

        var jsondata = {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Test Name",
            "price": 100,
            "city": "XYZ"
        };

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'My URL HERE',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "'application/json; charset=utf-8",
            },
            data: jsondata ,

        }).then(function(result) {
             alert("yes, you have posted the data !");
        }, function(error) {
            alert("failed")
        });
    };
});
```